# Sharepoint 2010 folder level views on document library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, view

I have a document library in SharePoint 2010 and want to create different views on the basis of attribute values like

1. View1 shows only those folder which have Close projects
2. View2 shows only those folder which have Active projects

so I want to create folder level column which can be set as close/active.

Any Idea to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use content types for this. You just need to create content types and setting the parent content type group as Folder Content Types and setting the parent content type to Folder. Once done you can create a new site column and use it later on your list's folder.

A more detailed step by step instruction can be found [here](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2007/08/sharepoint-how-to-create-links-from.html).